# In R, a question about regular expressions -stringr package (str_remove_all)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

In R , there is a character as 'X201A61NA231.1W', i want to replace all the letters and 'NA' ,'.1'. But below code failed . Anyone can help? thanks.

```
library(stringr)
t_chart <- 'X201A61NA231.1W'
t_chart %>% str_remove_all('[X|NA|W|(/.1)]')
```

Comment: the wishd result  is '20161231'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[X|NA|W|(/.1)]` pattern is a *character class*. It matches any *single* char defined in the class. So, it matches `X`, `|`, `N`, `A`, `W`, `(`, `/`, `.`, `1` or `)` chars.

When you need to match *sequences* of chars, you should use *grouping constructs* like capturing or non-capturing groups with alternation (`(...|...)` or `(?:...|...)`), or - if these alternations are the entire pattern, just use the `|` OR operator to separate alternatives without any grouping.

To match any letters, you can use `\p{L}` or `[:alpha:]`, or even `[a-zA-Z]` if you need to only handle ASCII letters. To match a dot followed with `1` you need `\.1` (note the escaped dot since it is a special regex metacharacter).

Your code can be fixed as

```r
t_chart %>% str_remove_all('[[:alpha:]]+|\\.1')
t_chart %>% str_remove_all('\\p{L}+|\\.1')
t_chart %>% str_remove_all('[a-zA-Z]+|\\.1')
```

Note the double escaped backslash in an R string literal.

Comment: FYI See [this approach demo](https://ideone.com/Jlr1f5) (with `str_replace_all`, that site has no support from `str_remove_all`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

```
t_chart <- 'X201A61NA231.1W'
stringr::str_remove_all(t_chart, '[A-Z]|\\.1')
#[1] "20161231"
```

In base R using `gsub` -

```
gsub("[A-Z]|\\.1", "", t_chart)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the single characters that you want to remove in a character class and repeat that 1 or more times, as there is `NA` but also a single `A` and use the alternation `|` outside of the character class to match `.1` with a backslash to escape the dot.

Note that inside the character class the `|` matches a pipe char.

```
t_chart <- 'X201A61NA231.1W'
gsub("[XWNA]+|\\.1", "", t_chart)
```

Output

```
[1] "20161231"
```